# JSDoc - How do I document a static method in a superclass that returns an instance of its subclass?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

So I have a base class kind of like this:

```js
class BaseAPIClass {
    /**
     * Async factory
     * Does some async operation, then instantiates the inheriting class.
     *
     * @param {String} id
     *
     * @returns {Promise<???>}
     */
    static async create(id) {
        const data = await fetchFromNetwork(id)
        return new this.prototype.constructor(data)
    }
}
```

And a subclass kind of like this:

```js
class RadAPIClass extends BaseAPIClass {
    /**
     * Output a compliment.
     * @param {name} [name='my dude']
     */
    complimentJorts(name = 'my dude') {
        const possibleCompliments = ['gnarly', 'tubular', 'bodacious', 'radical', 'sick']
        const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleCompliments.length)
        const compliment = possibleCompliments[i]
        console.log(`Those are some ${compliment} jorts, ${name}!`)
    }
}
```

My question is this:

How do I document the return type for `BaseAPIClass.create()` in a way that correctly tells readers & intellisense that `RadAPIClass.create()` returns a `{Promise<RadAPIClass>}`?

```js
async function main()
{
    const rad = await RadAPIClass.create()
    rad.complimentJorts() // I want VSCode to be able to autocomplete this method for me.
}
```

Comment: how can the super class have knowledge of the sub class?

Comment: The `static create()` method gets inherited by the child class, so at the time of calling `RadAPIClass.create()` the `this.prototype.constructor` reference in the base class basically translates to to `RadAPIClass.prototype.constructor`

Comment: When you now have 20 subclasses you want them all to be included in the type? The `BaseAPIClass::create` returns a `BaseAPIClass`, all sub class instances are a `BaseAPIClass`. Why do you name a class with `Class`?

Comment: I don't, it's just demonstration code. The truth is, if you execute the code above (define or remove `fetchFromNetwork`), the `create` method doesn't just return `Promise<BaseAPIClass>`, it returns a promise for whatever class you called it on. So `RadAPIClass.create()` returns `Promise<RadAPIClass>`. If I had 20 subclasses each one would return `Promise<ThisSubType>`, and I want the return type to indicate what's being returned. It's like an async constructor.

I'm more or less looking for a `@returns {Promise<this.constructor>}` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older and wiser. The answer is a generic `@this`.

```js
class BaseAPIClass {
    /**
     * Async factory
     * Does some async operation, then instantiates the inheriting class.
     *
     * @template {{new(...args: any): any}} T
     * @this {T}
     *
     * @param {String} id
     *
     * @returns {Promise<InstanceType<T>>}
     */
    static async create(id) {
        const data = await fetchFromNetwork(id)
        return new this.prototype.constructor(data)
    }
}
```

The generic `T` is inferred from the type of the subclass because of `@this {T}`, so a return type of `Promise<InstanceType<T>>` (remember `T` is a `typeof BaseAPIClass` or `typeof RadAPIClass` and not an instance type) resolves to the correct class.